How to Implement Child Process in InversifyJS?
I'm trying to implement a child process using Node.js and InversifyJS in my application, but I'm encountering issues when trying to correctly inject services within the child process. I need to use dependency injection with InversifyJS inside the child process and invoke a method that warms up some cached data. The code works without InversifyJS, but I'm not sure how to set up the container and inject dependencies properly when forking a new process.
Here is what I've done so far:
Parent process (where the child process is invoked):
const child = fork(join(__dirname, './products/fmc-warmup-child.js'));

child.send({ data: '' });

child.on('message', result => {
  console.log('Result from child:', result);
});

Child process (fmc-warmup-child.ts):
import ProductStrategy from '../../product/product.strategy';
import ioc from '../../../core/ioc/index';
import { BrowsingService } from '../../ps/products/browsing-service';
import { CachePopulatorService } from './cache-populator.service';

process.on('message', msg => {
  let service: CachePopulatorService;

  ioc.clearMetadata();
  ioc.bindToSelf(BrowsingService);
  ioc.bindToSelf(ProductStrategy);

  ioc.bindToSelf(CachePopulatorService);
  service = ioc.get(CachePopulatorService);

  const result = service.warmUpCache();
  process.send(result);
});

What I did:

I forked a child process using Node.js fork() method.

I'm attempting to set up the InversifyJS IoC container inside the child process and bind the necessary services.

I send a message from the parent process to the child, which should trigger the warmUpCache method in the child process.


Problem:

How do I properly use InversifyJS to manage dependencies in a child process created via fork()?

Are there any best practices or patterns for using InversifyJS in a child process in Node.js?


Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated!
